# Android autocomplete background yellow color on EditText

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been trying different solutions without success to remove the yellow paint of autocomplete on textfield. 
I tried 3 different ways to use:

```
<item name="android:autofilledHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

tried in version v26, with tools:targetApi="o" and tools:ignore="NewApi". Also tried the solution on developers.android to create a transparent shape.

This is my style:

```
<style name="editText" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:autofilledHighlight" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/lightGray</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/darkGray</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/lightGray2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/mainOrange</item>
</style>
```

this is my EditText:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_emailinputlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/editText"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="55dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/login_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:theme="@style/editText"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/mainOrange" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

This is my gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
}
```

Everything works except the autocomplete yellow paint. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: On what android version you're running it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-optimize#highlighted